Is SOLID's Dependency Inversion actually Dependency Redirection?
I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my head around the Dependency Inversion principle of SOLID, I' think I might be mixing up concept with implementation... so I figured I could post my thought process here and hopefully someone can tell me what I'm missing.
I think that the thing confusing me is the "Inversion" part, since I'm thinking in literally inverting the dependency, like: instead of the high-level module depending on the low-level module, the low-level model should depend on the high-level module.
But considering the principle's statements that:

High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules
Instead, both modules should depend on abstractions
Those abstractions should not depend on details

And considering the usage of Interfaces, then I'm thinking that what DIP suggests is not inversion but more like... redirection?
In this sense, both the high-level and the low-level modules have their dependencies redirected to an Interface, which the low-level module should implement (this way we can change the low-level model for another implementation without the high-level module complaint).
I made this sketch to illustrate:

Am I on the right track?

Terms here are not accurate, that's not math, don't treat them seriously. Inversion here only means that introducing abstraction/interface makes the relation between types not matching to natural control flow. It's all about loose coupling story, as i get it.

Does it make a difference whether you call it redirection or inversion?

"We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection."

Whether or not the DIP implies the kind of sketch shown in the OP depends on how one interprets the word interface. Does it imply a language-level interface, as in Java or C#? Or does it rather indicate any kind of API?
In any case, however,

"clients [...] own the abstract interfaces"
- Robert C. Martin, APPP

where by client is indicated the high-level module. In other words, high-level code gets to define what interactions look like. It can do that by defining an interface, a polymorphic base class, a first-class function, or even pure interactions, if you will.
You don't need a separate 'interface' module for that. Just point your dependencies inward.
